# How to use multi config in KCFinder

Tags: tinymce, kcfinder

I have Project A and Project B use KCFinder too. Now, i want to when run project A, it's use config:

```
$_CONFIG = array(
    'uploadURL' => "Url Of Project A",
    'uploadDir' => "Dir of Project A"
);
```

And when run project B, it's use config:

```
$_CONFIG = array(
    'uploadURL' => "Url Of Project B",
    'uploadDir' => "Dir of Project B"
);
```

My editor is Tinymce 4, I tried many different ways but it's always get default config (Project A)

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample case I hope could help you. In my case, I am using a sub domain to store images rather than in main. Just to speed up loading. And worked on other sub domain as administration.

My main web is : mainweb.com and I store images in img.mainweb.com. The editor is in adm.mainweb.com with login. And the setting in localhost is :

```
    'uploadURL' => "http://img.mainweb.com/blog/blog_content",
    'uploadDir' => "D:/xampp/htdocs/mainweb/img/blog/blog_content",
```

Use real path on live server such as : /home/..user../www/folder1/folder2/ or other path depending on your server configuration. In your case, you can configure uploadURL with your Url http://..... and uploadDir with your real path directory.